# Handling thousands of async POST requests in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous

I've encountered an issue with my Node.js Telegram bot. The bot is responsible for sending approximately 1000 requests per second. Given Node.js's reputation for fast request handling, it seemed like the ideal choice for this task.

I've set up a cronjob to periodically check the getConnectionCount result every 2 seconds. Generally, this function returns N1->0, indicating that everything is functioning smoothly. However, during periods of exceptionally high usage, I've noticed that getConnectionCount returns unusually high results, such as:

> 14.03 05:07:41 N95->1431
>
> 14.03 05:07:43 N81->1440
>
> 14.03 05:07:45 N99->1976
>
> 14.03 05:07:47 N96->1437
>
> 14.03 05:07:49 N100->1979
>
> 14.03 05:07:51 N84->1455
>
> 14.03 05:07:53 N101->1977
>
> 14.03 05:07:55 N101->1992

Initially, I suspected that these spikes were due to latency issues with the Telegram server. However, upon further investigation, I found that sending curl requests (e.g., sendMessage) to the Telegram server directly from the same server yielded consistently fast responses.

Interestingly, a quick remedy for this issue is to simply restart the Node.js app using pm2 restart app. After the restart, the bot resumes normal operation, with getConnectionCount consistently returning N1->0.

I'm puzzled as to why these requests get stuck after some time, despite the server being capable of handling the same volume of requests. What might be causing this?

My node app code:

```
var express = require('express');
const axios = require("axios");
const Noderavel = require("@movilizame/noderavel");
const nodelaravel = require("node-laravel-queue");
const {uuid} = require("node-laravel-queue/lib/tools");
const redis = require("redis");
const {serialize} = require("php-serialize");
var app = express();

app.use(express.json({limit: '100mb'}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({limit: '100mb', extended: true, parameterLimit: 50000}));

const nocache = require('nocache');
const processId = process.pid;

app.use(nocache());

app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
});


let connectionCount = 0;
let pendingCount = 0;

// Middleware to track connections
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    connectionCount++;

    res.on('finish', () => {
        connectionCount--;
    });

    next();
});

app.get("/getConnectionCount", function (req, res) {
    res.send(connectionCount.toString() + "->" + pendingCount.toString());
});

async function sendPostRequest(url, postData) {

    try {


        pendingCount++;

        // Make the POST request using axios
        const response = await axios.post(url, postData);

        pendingCount--;

        return response.data;
        // console.log(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        pendingCount--;

        return error.response ? error.response.data : error.message;
    }

}

app.post('/sendRequest/:bot_token', async function (req, res) {
    // for (let index = 0; index < 1e7; index++);

    let bot_token = req.params['bot_token'];

    const postData = req.body;

    let method = postData.method;
    let data = postData.data;
    let get_result = parseInt(postData.get_result);

    let url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + bot_token + "/" + method;

    if (get_result == 1) {
        res.send(await sendPostRequest(url, data));
        return;
    }

    sendPostRequest(url, data);
    res.send("1");
});



var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log(`Server Started in process ${processId}`);
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
server.keepAliveTimeout = 65000; // Ensure all inactive connections are terminated by the ALB, by setting this a few seconds higher than the ALB idle timeout
server.headersTimeout = 66000; // Ensure the headersTimeout is set higher than the keepAliveTimeout due to this nodejs regression bug: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/27363
server.setTimeout(10000);
```

Comment: You'd still need to optimize your setup, like running multiple Node.js processes to share the workload over more than one CPU core, configuring `keepAlive` for HTTP connections (or use HTTP/2), replace `axios` by something more lightweight, etc. And that all assumes that the underlying OS is already configured properly for these kinds of workloads.